# IP Address changes after sending it over network stream

Tags: c, networking

I'm creating a makeshift querying protocol and need to send IP addresses over a network. The IP addresses are stored in structs with someother information and then the structs are sent over the network. The problem is that the IP address "changes" after being sent over the network.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Query {
      int TTL;
      int pointer;
      int reverse;
      struct sockaddr_in destination;
      struct sockaddr_in path[];
};

int main() {

      int fd;
      char routerAddr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN], neighbourAddr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
      struct sockaddr_in address;

      bzero((char *)&address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
      address.sin_family = AF_INET;
      address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.1.5.34");
      address.sin_port = htons(50000);

      struct Query q;
      q.TTL = 5;
      q.reverse = 0;
      q.pointer = 0;
      q.path[q.pointer] = address;
      q.destination.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("255.255.255.255");
      q.pointer++;

      char routerBuf[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
      inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(q.path[0].sin_addr), routerBuf, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
      printf("1[%s][%d]\n", routerBuf, q.pointer);

      if ((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error creating sending socket.\nExiting.\n");
            exit(-1);
     }

  if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error binding to socket.\nExiting.\n");
        perror("");
        exit(-1);
  }

  struct sockaddr_in n;
  memset((char *)&n, 0, sizeof(n));
  n.sin_family = AF_INET;
  n.sin_port = htons(50001);
  n.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.1.5.49");

  if (sendto(fd, &q, sizeof(struct Query), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&n, sizeof(n)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error sending to neighbhour.\nExiting.\n");
        perror("");
        exit(-1);
  }
```

}

The receiver is similar, it uses recvfrom and stores what it receives in a struct. Printing out the IP address results in a different IP Address. 10.1.5.34 --> 2.0.195.81

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Query {
      int TTL;
      int pointer;
      int reverse;
      struct sockaddr_in destination;
      struct sockaddr_in path[];
};

int main() {

      int fd, sd;
      char routerAddr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN], neighbourAddr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
      struct sockaddr_in address, neighbourAddress, r;
      socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(neighbourAddress);

      if ((sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error creating sending socket.\nExiting.\n");
            exit(-1);
      }

      bzero((char *)&r, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
      r.sin_family = AF_INET;
      r.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.1.5.49");
      r.sin_port = htons(50001);

      if (bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&r, sizeof(r)) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error binding to socket.\nExiting.\n");
            perror("");
            exit(-1);
      }

      struct Query queryR; 
      int len = recvfrom(sd, &queryR, sizeof(struct Query), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&neighbourAddress, &addrlen);

      char routerBuf[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
      inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(queryR.path[0].sin_addr), routerBuf, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
      printf("1[%s][%d]\n", routerBuf, queryR.pointer);

      bzero((char *)&address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
      address.sin_family = AF_INET;
      address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.1.5.49");
      address.sin_port = htons(50000);

      struct Query q;
      q.TTL = 5;
      q.reverse = 0;
      q.pointer = 0;
      q.path[q.pointer] = address;
      q.destination.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("255.255.255.255");
      q.pointer++;

      inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(q.path[0].sin_addr), routerBuf, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
      printf("1[%s][%d]\n", routerBuf, q.pointer);

      if ((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error creating sending socket.\nExiting.\n");
            exit(-1);
      }

      if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address)) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error binding to socket.\nExiting.\n");
            perror("");
            exit(-1);
      }

      struct sockaddr_in n;
      memset((char *)&n, 0, sizeof(n));
      n.sin_family = AF_INET;
      n.sin_port = htons(50001);
      n.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.1.5.49");

      if (sendto(fd, &q, sizeof(struct Query), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&n, sizeof(n)) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error sending to neighbhour.\nExiting.\n");
            perror("");
            exit(-1);
      }
}
```

Comment: Note that you're using a [flexible array member](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) in your `Query` struct, but not accounting for its size when sending the packet. You should also be allocating dynamically with extra space for the elements of the array.

Comment: @MartinTörnwall Yup that was it. Thanks.

Comment: Please answer the question with your solution.

Comment: Moral: don't use structs as network protocols. Use network protocols as network protocols. Define the protocol in octets and write a library to send and receive it.